# Get the 1st and next value inside an array

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an array like this

`var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`;

How can I get the output like this?

```
console.log(1,2);
console.log(2,3);
console.log(3,4);
```

and so on.. as of now this is my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 /* Dont know what to do */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to stop one step before the end of the array in your cycle and print the current and next value

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
for (var i = 0; i < data.length -1; i++) {
    console.log(data[i], data[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: this will throw `index out of bound exception` in the last iteration

Comment: Nope, I stop one iteration earlier (`data.length -1`)

Answer (score 2):

You could use reduce with returning the last element as new element.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

data.reduce((a, b) => (console.log(a, b), b));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 if (i+1 < data.length) {
   console.log(data[i], data[i+1]);
 } else {
   console.log("finished")
}
```

or just

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 if (i+1 < data.length-1) {
   console.log(data[i], data[i+1]);
 }
```

you need the else block to prevent `index out of bound exception`

Comment: Or you could just make the loop one iteration shorter.

Comment: true that :D will change this